# Save image in Django from Android app

Tags: android, django, django-models, okhttp, imagefield

I was having problem while saving picture in Django from Android app. I searched and finally solved the problem. I am sharing this so that it might help. Please see the answer below.

Comment: It is kind of you to add your solution, thank you. However, the above is not a question as per the Stack Overflow guidelines. Would you be able to rewrite the above to make it into a question? This is quite hard to do, since it needs to contain the problem you had prior to finding the solution. However, please do try, so we can avoid it being put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to implement things according to your own specifications. I am just showing you as a generic example

I have used [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) in my android app to send data on network (including pic)

Android AsyncTask Code (doInBackground Method)

```
  RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("filename","filename",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), new File(file.getPath())))
                    //.addFormDataPart("other_field", "other_field_value")
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .header("Authorization", "Token " + myToken)
                    .url(myUrl).post(formBody).build();
            Response response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
```

My view.py Code

```
def rechargeapplication(request):
    user=#get your own object
    uploadpic = request.FILES['filename']
    user.picture.save("image.jpg",uploadpic)
    user.save()
    return JsonResponse({'result':'Success'})
```

How I created imageField in models.py

```
picture=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos" , null=True, blank=True)
```

**if you are using ImageField then you will have to install "Pillow"**
Also make sure that you specify MEDIA_ROOT & MEDIA_URL in settings.py....I am showing you how I did it

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and at the end of urls.py add this(as I was in debug mode that is why my implementation...)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```